# Method Not Allowed (POST): /cbvdelete/5/ Method Not Allowed: /cbvdelete/5/

Tags: django

[image: this the error i got when i run this code,this is the error i get]

i am not able to run this code

viwes.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse

from . models import Task
from . forms import Taskform
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView,DeleteView



class Tasklistview(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'home.html'
    context_object_name = 'task'

class Detailview(DetailView):
    model=Task
    template_name = "details.html"
    context_object_name = 'task'

class Updateview(UpdateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = "update.html"
    context_object_name = "task"
    fields = ('name', 'priority', 'date')
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('todoapp:cbvdetail',kwargs={'pk':self.object.id})

class Deleteview(DetailView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('todoapp:home')
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views
    app_name='todoapp'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.home,name='home'),
        path('delete/<int:id>/',views.delete,name='delete'),
        path('edit/<int:id>/',views.update,name='update'),
        path('cbvhome/',views.Tasklistview.as_view(),name='home'),
        path('cbvdetail/<int:pk>/',views.Detailview.as_view(),name='cbvdetail'),
        path('cbvupdate/<int:pk>/',views.Updateview.as_view(),name='edit'),


     ]
```

when i run this code i am getting a error this page isn't working right now
i am not able to run this code
gngnitgbnugriujvnnvtvnviuvntnvtvitu

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting you `Deleteview` from a `DetailView`, not a `DeleteView`, hence the error:

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView

class Deleteview(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('todoapp:home')
```

I would however strongly advise *not* to give your views names like `Deleteview`, since it is easy to confuse this with the Django builtin class-based views. Usually the model is specified in the name, so `TaskDeleteView` instead of `Deleteview`:

```
class TaskDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('todoapp:home')
```